# Ruby on Rails: How to ignore the first validation of the first saved object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code require a user to have a sponsor id except the first user. My code is

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
        attr_accessor :remember_token    
        before_save {email.downcase!}    
        validates :first_name, :presence =>true, length: {maximum: 50}    
        validates :last_name, :presence => true, length: {maximum: 50}   
        VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i    
        validates :email, :presence =>true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with:     VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }    
        has_secure_password
        validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil:true

    .
    .
    .

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "User"
        validates :sponsor, presence:true
        validate :sponsor_id_valid
        def sponsor_id_valid
          errors.add(:sponsor_id, "is not exist") if  User.exists? sponsor_id: sponsor_id
        end
        #Validate that the user isV exist in the data
        def validate_sponsor_id


     errors.add(:sponsor_id,"is not exist")   if User.find(self.sponsor_id).blank?


    end


      end
```

I require that the User need to have `sponsor_id` for all user exept the `User.first`. I tried `unless` method but it didn't give me a desired outcome. The way I test the code is that I create a test code which give the first user to have a `sponsor_id` to be `nil` and the test failed. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def sponsor_id_valid
  if self.sponsor_id.blank? && self != User.first
    errors.add(:sponsor_id, "is not exist")
  end
end
```

EDIT: to take account of the case where there isn't an existing first user yet, (which we want to pass) the logic could be changed to:

```
if self.sponsor_id.blank? && (first_user = User.first) && (self != first_user)
  #add a validation error
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this code thank you so much. However, this have problem because it check `self != User.first` before the User.save so the `User.first` is not exist yet. Are there any other way that I can solve this problem ?

Comment: I tried but it said `rake db:seed
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)`

Comment: Re the first comment: see my edit.  Re the second comment: which line is that error message referring to?